# awk to update file if value within range

Tags: awk

I have a `file2` with ~1400 `$5` values before the `-` that are "unknown".  What I am trying to do is use the text in `$2` of `file2` to update those "unknown" values in `file1`.  In `$1` of `file1` there are a set of numbers that can be used to update the "unknown" if it in the range of `$4` of `file2`. I am really not sure where to start but maybe the `awk` below is a start or there is probably a better way.  Thank you :).

**file1**

```
       `$1`           `$2`
 chr6:3224495-3227968 TUBB2B
 chr16:89988417-90002505 TUBB3
```

**file2**

```
chr16   89985657    89986630    chr16:89985657-89986630 MC1R-2270|gc=63.5
chr16   89989779    89989898    chr16:89989779-89989898 unknown-2271|gc=73.9
chr16   89998969    89999097    chr16:89998969-89999097 unknown-2272|gc=57
chr16   89999866    89999996    chr16:89999866-89999996 unknown-2273|gc=55.4
chr16   90001127    90002222    chr16:90001127-90002222 unknown-2274|gc=63.9
chr17   1173848 1174575 chr17:1173848-1174575   BHLHA9-3|gc=78.7
```

**desired output** (`unknown updated to TUBB3 because the TUBB3 because the $4 value is within the range of $1`).

```
chr16   89985657    89986630    chr16:89985657-89986630 MC1R-2270|gc=63.5
chr16   89989779    89989898    chr16:89989779-89989898 TUBB3-2271|gc=73.9
chr16   89998969    89999097    chr16:89998969-89999097 TUBB3-2272|gc=57
chr16   89999866    89999996    chr16:89999866-89999996 TUBB3-2273|gc=55.4
chr16   90001127    90002222    chr16:90001127-90002222 TUBB3-2274|gc=63.9
chr17   1173848 1174575 chr17:1173848-1174575   BHLHA9-3|gc=78.7
```

**awk**

```
awk '
NR == FNR {min[$1]=$4; next}
{
    for (id in min) 
        if ([id] = $5 && [id]) {
            print $0, id
            break
        }
}
' file1 file2
```

edit:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{split($1,a,/[:-]/)
                       rstart[a[1]]=a[2]
                       rend[a[1]]=a[3]
                       value[a[1]]=$2
                       next} 
 $5~/unknown/ && $2>=rstart[$1] && $3<=rend[$1]
                      {sub(/unknown/,value[$1],$5)}1' file1 file2 | 
column -t > output


chr16   89985657    89986630    chr16:89985657-89986630 MC1R-2270|gc=63.5
chr16   89989779    89989898    chr16:89989779-89989898 unknown-2271|gc=73.9
chr16   89989779    89989898    chr16:89989779-89989898 TUBB3-2271|gc=73.9
chr16   89998969    89999097    chr16:89998969-89999097 unknown-2272|gc=57
chr16   89998969    89999097    chr16:89998969-89999097 TUBB3-2272|gc=57
chr16   89999866    89999996    chr16:89999866-89999996 unknown-2273|gc=55.4
chr16   89999866    89999996    chr16:89999866-89999996 TUBB3-2273|gc=55.4
chr16   90001127    90002222    chr16:90001127-90002222 unknown-2274|gc=63.9
chr16   90001127    90002222    chr16:90001127-90002222 TUBB3-2274|gc=63.9
chr17   1173848 1174575 chr17:1173848-1174575   BHLHA9-3|gc=78.7
```

Comment: I think you mixed up `file1` and `file2` in the text a few times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{split($1,a,/[:-]/)
                           rstart[a[1]]=a[2]
                           rend[a[1]]=a[3]
                           value[a[1]]=$2
                           next} 
     $5~/unknown/ && $2>=rstart[$1] && $3<=rend[$1]
                          {sub(/unknown/,value[$1],$5)}1' file1 file2 | 
  column -t

chr16  89985657  89986630  chr16:89985657-89986630  MC1R-2270|gc=63.5
chr16  89989779  89989898  chr16:89989779-89989898  TUBB3-2271|gc=73.9
chr16  89998969  89999097  chr16:89998969-89999097  TUBB3-2272|gc=57
chr16  89999866  89999996  chr16:89999866-89999996  TUBB3-2273|gc=55.4
chr16  90001127  90002222  chr16:90001127-90002222  TUBB3-2274|gc=63.9
chr17  1173848   1174575   chr17:1173848-1174575    BHLHA9-3|gc=78.7
```

modifies the original spacing so piped to `column -t` for tabular format.

Comment: `rstart` is not the best choice for variable names, it's too similar to a built-in awk variable: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#Auto_002dset

Comment: Also, you only need one split: `split($1, a, /[:-]/)`

Comment: I added an edit with the output where the unknown gets replaced on a new line instead of on the same line.  Thank you :).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow?  Why are you using that script?  What does `[id]` mean?

Comment: I am using the script you provided kindly to produce the output, as mine did not work.  Thank you :).

Comment: I'm not sure it will produce the output you posted. There are no extra print statements, so each line should occur at most once.  Perhaps your `awk` is broken.  Do you know what are you using?  You can check with `awk --version` command.

Comment: `GNU 4.0.1` is my `awk version`.  Thank you :)

Comment: OK, perhaps some formatting issue, edit you script such that the condition `$5~/unknown/...` and the block following `{sub(/unkn...` are on the same line.