# awk to print lines not found between two files

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to print out those lines in `file2` that are not between `$2` and `$3` in `file1`. I think it's close but currently it is printing out the matches. Basically, the opposite of what it is doing.

**awk with current output**

```
awk '
NR==FNR{for(i=$2;i<=$3;++i) d[$1,i] = $6; next}
d[$1,$2]{print $0}' file2 file1
chr1 948953 948956 chr1:948953-948956 . ISG15
chr1 949363 949858 chr1:949363-949858 . ISG15
chr19 42373737 42373856 chr19:42373737-42373856 . RPS19
```

**file1**

```
chr1 948953 948956 chr1:948953-948956 . ISG15
chr1 949363 949858 chr1:949363-949858 . ISG15
chr19 42373737 42373856 chr19:42373737-42373856 . RPS19
```

**file2**

```
chr1 948796 949006 chr1:948796-949006 . ISG15
chr1 949313 949969 chr1:949313-949969 . ISG15
chr19 42363937 42364409 chr19:42363937-42364409 . RPS19
chr19 42364286 42364565 chr19:42364286-42364565 . RPS19
chr19 42373718 42373873 chr19:42373718-42373873 . RPS19
```

desired output

```
chr19 42363937 42364409 chr19:42363937-42364409 . RPS19
chr19 42364286 42364565 chr19:42364286-42364565 . RPS19
```

description

```
line 1,2, and 5 match or fall into the range of `file1` and don't need to be printed.
```

To get the output desired I tried and it did execute with no results:

**awk**

```
awk '
NR==FNR{for(i=$2;i<=$3;++i) d[$1,i] = $6; next}
!d[$1,$2]{print $0}' file2 file1
```

Thank you :).

Comment: It's unclear. What are the rules to decide if lines are the same or different? What field(s) do you use for the comparison? The 4th field is always different between your two files.

Comment: I see now I am going to have to use a better approach then a single `key` as it appears that the `$4` overlaps or falls within `file1`.  I will add better details shortly. Thank you :).

Comment: I made an edit to the post and will also try something new but wanted to post more details.  Thank you :).

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. Are you trying to compare the whole of each line or just $4? If $4 are you trying to match it within a range or exactly? If you want help, [edit] your question so it simply states what it is you want, not a history of your thought process as you figured out what you want which is what it appears to be now. Make sure your sample input/output covers all possible cases you care about but is still concise.

Comment: @Chris: don't you already have various solutions for the range overlap question?  Can't you dig down from your old questions and modify them?  Here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878490/awk-to-update-file-if-value-within-range/35878800#35878800

Comment: I am re-reading them and trying again.  Thank you :).

Comment: I made edits to the post based on the comments and am closer but not there yet.  Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while read; do
  grep -q "^$REPLY$" file1 || echo "$REPLY"
done< file2
```

Comment: That will fail given many possible contents of either file and will be extremely inefficient. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for a discussion on about half of the issues but there are more...